# Comparing two alphanumeric room numbers to determine floor prefix

Tags: excel, vba, range, comparison, match

I have been working on a project for work where I create room lists based on ranges i.e. 1-3,5 returns 1,2,3,5 in new rows on another sheet.  I even was able to read another set of ranges from another cell and compare it for doubles. so it the second cell was 1-3 the list would be, 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B, 3A, 3B, 5A.  The next step will be to compare numbers in the first range to determine prefixes and suffixes, assign them to a variable, remove them, do the comparisons and re-insert them when writing rows.  A good example of a range would be 5N01-5N05 would need to return 5n01, 5n02, 5n03, 5n04, 5n05.  Another example of a range would be 10011-X - 10015-x would need to return 10011-x, 10012-x 10013-x, 10014-x, 10015-x

Any help would be appreciated. I have seen examples that have just split all text and numbers but have not stored the number
In my head I would need to write a formula that grabs the first two numbers, starts at the left, makes notes of the position it is comparing and goes down the line until it hits a unique value. The position can be fed back to read the first however many characters and delete them before entering the range formula and then reinserting when writing the list. The same would be done starting from the right to determine suffix so in the last room list it would go

(10011-x - 10015-x)

- Left most character 1 is 1, matches both 1st positions, move to next
- Next character 2 is 0, matches both 2nd positions, move to next
- Next character 3 is 0, matches both 3rd positions, move to next
- Next character 4 is 1, matches both 4th positions, move to next
  -Next character 5 is 1, does not match both 5th positions, stop
- Prefix = characters 1-4 of first number, 1001
- Rightmost character 7 is x, matched both 7th position, move to next
  -next character 6 is "-", matches both 6th positions, move to next
- next character 5 is 1, does not match both 5th positions, stop
- suffix = characters 6-7 of first number, -x

That's where I need help. From there I could manage to extract the true range
1-5 after the prefix and suffix is removed and populate them in the list at the end.

Comment: Not only unclear but way to broad in my opinion. You talk as if you have coded something. Please could you share the code and say what isn't working? Also, IMHO, it would be really helpful if all the rules governing string handling were bullet-pointed and made very clear with examples. I was lost by line 3.

Comment: Show us some data and expected output. For example, where I got lost on line three I think you meant if you had (1-3,5),(1-3) you would like the whole lot renamed so as to be distinct giving you {1,2,3,5,1,2,3} => {1A,1B,2A,2B,3A,3B,5A} . i.e. I think you mean duplicate where you say double?   But I don't really understand how I would know when this should happen? Am I looping 2 columns and comparing column 1 with column 2 on a row for row basis? Where am i outputting my generated strings - in one column of the new row in another sheet? .......This is the detail we need.

Comment: There is quite a lot of regex required to determine this just thinking about this range as an example:  10011-x - 10015-x.  You have now introduced additional "-". I am voting to close, at present, as way to broad. I did work my way through and determine, I think, most of the rules but even then....

Comment: @pnuts As in I should refer OP to this? It looks useful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the broadness. Just have a lot of moving pieces on this doc
I created some code to compare entries and spit out the prefixes and suffixes of room numbers
Here it is.  The next step is incorporating this into my other Sub that can read ranges like (1-5,7,9)  I want to be able for it to read (3N01-X-3N05-X, 3N07-X)
and I think with the comparing Sub below I am a little closer. I will try to be more direct with my next questions when I post a new one but this is answered

```
    Sub Prefix()
Sheet7.Range("B1").Select

Dim Entry1 As String
Dim Entry2 As String

Dim currentCharacter As String
Dim currentCharacter2 As String
Dim pCount As Integer
Dim pCurrent As String
Dim Prefix As String
Dim pArray(1 To 10) As String
Dim sCount As Integer
Dim sCurrent As String
Dim Suffix As String
Dim sArray(1 To 10) As String


Entry1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
Entry2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

    For pCount = 1 To Len(Entry1)

        currentCharacter = Mid(Entry1, pCount, 1)
        currentCharacter2 = Mid(Entry2, pCount, 1)

        If currentCharacter = currentCharacter2 Then

         pArray(pCount) = currentCharacter

            NextRow2 = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           Sheet7.Cells(NextRow2, "G") = currentCharacter
         Else
         Prefix = Join(pArray, "")

    MsgBox Prefix

            GoTo Suffix

        End If

    Next

    Suffix:
    For sCount = 1 To Len(Entry1)

        currentCharacter = Right(Entry1, sCount)
        currentCharacter2 = Right(Entry2, sCount)

        If currentCharacter = currentCharacter2 Then

         sArray(sCount) = currentCharacter

            NextRow2 = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           Sheet7.Cells(NextRow2, "G") = currentCharacter
          Suffix = currentCharacter
         Else


    MsgBox Suffix

            Exit Sub

        End If

    Next





End Sub
```